# Azure Usage Details Billing API

Tags: python, azure

I want to get the usage details by billing period on azure.
For that am hitting the azure Python SDK API.
But in the response am getting `three entries for the same date.`
The only difference is in the id's and the `pretax_cost`.

Here's the link for the API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-consumption/azure.mgmt.consumption.operations.usagedetailsoperations?view=azure-python#list-expand-none--filter-none--skiptoken-none--top-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-

Can anyone tell why am getting three entries for same date.
Does the three entries depict something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code you're using and also the result you're getting. Without actually looking at these, it's just not possible to say what's wrong.

Comment: Got it, entries were depicting costs for different aspects like vm cost, data transfercost, networking cost, like these.